# How to fix VS Code extension cash issue?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I installed some extensions in VS Code, but after that my all code looks none-style.
How to fix this issue? Which extension should I install for this? Color mode is not working. All code looks white.

> This is uncolored code.

[image]

> This is original code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved. Click the settings icon(bottom left) in VSCode and tap `Color Theme` or press `Ctrl+K,T`. And then choose the right theme according to your env.
Default theme of VSCode is  `Dark+ (default dark)`.
This solved problem.